# Responsive Canvas Size with P5.JS and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, p5.js

I need to make custom data visualisation elements with p5js. The theme is responsive, so the visuals need fit inside a certain width. Depending on the data within the visuals and the options or filters that are applied, the height will change.

I have seen [Responsive P5JS for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-p5js-for-wp/#description) but I’m not sure how to modify the size of the canvas without reloading the page.

Comment: Do you have any code that you are working on? We need some context to see the issue clearly.

Comment: Without more details it's hard to give you a definite solution, however the help for [`resizeCanvas`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/resizeCanvas) shows you how to use this function to change the canvas size and how to call it from `windowResized()` to change the size without reloading the page. Once you have that working you'll have to keep in mind that all your values in your sketch should be relative to `width` and `height` otherwise the canvas will change of size but what is drawn in the canvas will not be resized.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here, the WP CSS issue and the p5.js issue. Let's start with the WP CSS issue, I have two solutions for you. The first one might actually solve it of the box.

**CSS Issue**

**Solution 1**:
Try using easy-p5-js-block for WordPress: https://wordpress.com/plugins/easy-p5-js-block

**Solution 2:**: Add the following custom CSS classes to your WP theme:

```
.responsiveWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    height: 0;
}
.responsiveWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and add the class responsiveWrapper to your p5.js WP element.

**p5.js**

Now regarding the P5.js issue. the `setup()` function usually creates a canvas with a fixed width and height. Now you need to make sure to recreate the canvas or resize the canvas after WP resizes the p5 element. To do that add some logic to your code to handle windowResized() and make use of resizeCanvas()... from the p5.js documentation https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  describe('A gray canvas that takes up the entire browser window. It changes size to match the browser window.');
}

// Resize the canvas when the
// browser's size changes.
function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```